# Grails Spring Security authentication from a service

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

Since i've been using a dedicated service in my Grails app so as to make authentication working with a vaadin UI, i 'm having a problem to validate the login:

1) A new user is created in bootstrap and recorded to db (postgre)

```
User.withTransaction {
   User test = new User(
      username: "test",
      password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("password"),
      enabled: true,
      accountExpired: false,
      accountLocked: false,
      passwordExpired: false
   ).save()

Role dashManager = new Role(authority: "ROLE_USER").save()

new UserRole(user: test, role: dashManager).save()
```

2) The vaadin ui calls normally the grails service

```
boolean login(String username, String password) {
   try {
      println username + "----" + password
      security.signIn(username, password)
      return true
   } catch (SecurityServiceException e) {
      Notification.show("Login/Password incorrect", Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
      return false
   }
}
```

3) My securityService always returns invalid

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

@Transactional
class SecurityService {

    def springSecurityService
    def authenticationManager

    void signIn(String username, String password) {
        try {
            def authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            SCH.context.authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication)
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Invalid username/password")
        }
    }

    void signOut() {
        SCH.context.authentication = null
    }

    boolean isSignedIn() {
        return springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably double-encoding the password. Recent versions of the plugin generate a user/person domain class that encodes the password for you, so you don't need to call `springSecurityService.encodePassword("password")`, and if you do then it's encoded twice. This should work:

```
User test = new User(
   username: "test",
   password: "password",
   enabled: true
).save()
```

I omitted setting `accountExpired`, `accountLocked`, and `passwordExpired` to `false` since those are the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the springSecurityService to authenticate

```
 void signIn(String username, String password) {
        try {
            springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username, password)
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Invalid username/password")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only use `reauthenticate` when you want to force in a known-good authentication. The primary use of this method is to update the authentication after updating the database to ensure that the in-memory data is in sync (hence the name - it's `reauthenticate`, not `authenticate`). But if you want to actually validate the password, check that the user isn't locked, etc. then properly validating using the `ProviderManager` (the `authenticationManager` bean) is necessary.

Comment: As I'm using "digest" authentication i've implemented the service above to get sure to get the token... Anyway i had missed the encodePassword() which has been move to domain class in the last version (i.e beforeInsert())